# add macro parameter of type Dropdownlist umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I am using umbraco version 7.2.6 . I want to add macro parameter of type Dropdownlist .

How can I set source (data come from database ) of dropdownlist ??

thanks

Comment: take a look at [this](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/sql-dropdown-list-for-v7) package. you can create dropdown from database table

Answer (score 1):

Had the same situation, I am aware that the 'proper' way to do it would be like described in http://www.richardsoeteman.net/2010/01/04/createacustommacroparametertype.aspx, but for my purpose this would have been too much fuss. What I suggest here instead is not elegant, but it's easy to implement.

Create a macro parameter type **Numeric** and explain in the description which number stands for which result. In the Macro Partial View assign the number to the respective result.

**Example**

Description of the Macro parameter:

**Alias**: dimension

**Description**: 1: 300x225 2:400x300 3:600x450 4:800x600

**Type**: Numeric

Code in the Macro Partial View:

```
var defaultdim = "medium";
if (Model.MacroParameters["dimension"] != null)
{
    var dim = Convert.ToInt32( Model.MacroParameters["dimension"] );
    if(dim == 1) { defaultdim = "small"; }
    else if(dim == 2) { defaultdim = "medium"; }
    else if(dim == 3) { defaultdim = "large"; }
    else if(dim == 4) { defaultdim = "xlarge"; }
}
```

"small", "medium" ... are crop names and stand for the dimensions shown in the parameter description.